# How can I show display an error in an EditTextPreference's dialog when validation fails?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I've just discovered that the `EditText` on Android has a method called `setError` when invoked shows an error symbol in the `EditText`. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I'd like to display the same thing in the dialog of my `EditTextPreference` when the validation fails (e.g. the word was longer than 5 characters).

For this, I guess I'll need to extend the `EditTextPreference`, get the reference to the `EditText` in it and do the validation when a key is pressed. This should be rather simple but I'm quite lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the EditText object from within the EditTextPreference object.

All you need to to is extend it, and add a text change listener to the EditText which will perform validation as the user types.

Then use your custom preference in the xml.